# running position change smoothly in c# winform?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have an object that can move in any direction(user define) but as you can see, it doesn't move smoothly.
how can I improve this movement.

```
 private void timer2_Tick_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
           float xpos,yapos,yspos,dif;
           double atheta;
           if (aireplane1.Top >= brec.Top + 10)
           if (startmove && !airisdragging)
           {

                   Size aireplane_size =aireplane1.Size;
                   if (keynum>0 && keynum<180) {
                   atheta =  Math.Atan2(aireplane1.Location.Y , aireplane1.Location.X);
                  atheta = atheta *180 / Math.PI;
yspos = -(float)Math.Tan(Math.PI/2- keynum * (Math.PI / 180)) * aireplane1.Location.X;
                   dif = yspos-aireplane1.Location.Y;


 xpos =( aireplane1.Location.X)+2;
                   yspos = -(float)Math.Tan(Math.PI / 2-keynum * (Math.PI / 180)) * xpos;
                   yapos = yspos - dif;
                   aireplane1.SetBounds((int)xpos,(int)(yapos),aireplane_size.Width,aireplane_size.Height);
                   }
                   else if (keynum >180 && keynum < 360)
                   {
                       atheta = Math.Atan2(aireplane1.Location.Y, aireplane1.Location.X);
                       atheta = atheta * 180 / Math.PI;
                       yspos = -(float)Math.Tan(Math.PI / 2 - keynum * (Math.PI / 180)) * aireplane1.Location.X;
                       dif = yspos - aireplane1.Location.Y;


                       xpos = (aireplane1.Location.X) - 2;
                       yspos = -(float)Math.Tan(Math.PI / 2 - keynum * (Math.PI / 180)) * xpos;
                       yapos = yspos - dif;
                       aireplane1.SetBounds((int)xpos, (int)(yapos), aireplane_size.Width, aireplane_size.Height);


                   }
               }

       }
```

keeynum is user angle input.

by changing time intervals the movement become smoother but still the background of the path of airplane change when it across it, how can I fix this?

this is the video of this movement:
[movement video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1VMKLo4kW_W0GNtFYE6W4jr7b7mmdbzqf/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: I'm guessing its because winforms doesn't handle subpixel measurements

Comment: But you can draw stuff using `float` values. That's going to give you a much smoother flow (or flight?).

Comment: WinForms has its limitations when it comes to animation.  It will improve a bit if you lose the controls and draw everything into a double buffered container.

Comment: all x and y values are float but setbounds command uses int values, so i have to change them. Is there any way to replace this? @Jimi

Comment: both the form and the airplane container is double buffered. @LarsTech

Comment: You're moving a Control over another, which also causes all that tearing quite visible in the animation you posted. You should instead draw the image of your airplane over the map. It's quite simple if you set the map as the BackgrounImage of a PictureBox and draw the image on its surface. -- A PictureBox can have a BackgroundImage, an Image (overlaps the background with transparency) and what is drawn on its surface overlaps (with transparency) what's behind it -- The position of the drawing be can calculated and set using floating point values (`float` in Winforms, `double` in WPF)

Comment: @Jimi the problem is that the airplane isn't image, because of needs of rotating of it I created it with class to have fully control on it.

Comment: I don't know what *I created it with class* means and what is the problem with rotating an image, since it's a pretty common (and simple) thing to do.

Comment: @Jimi . Jimi thanks for your answers and I apologize because of my unclear questions.      let I explain more in detail:  the airplane can rotate by user defined number, also red arrow rotate and point to specific NDB by user too. this video show everything, if there is another way to do this please explain with example. [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1b8faR5EWdWEWzMK5HwaakwvluSMdQC4M/view?usp=sharing)